# How to make a number field dependant from a checkbox?

Tags: apex, validation-rule, number, field-dependencies

In sales orders I have 2 custom fields **Qnty** and **Free Qnty** and a checkbox **Free Qnty Only**. For orders, that have a number in Quantity it's possible to enter Free Quantity and the checkbox is set to false by default.

But if the checkbox **Free Qnty Only** is true, the **Free Qnty** should be uneditable. I know, that the field dependency can be set only between checkboxes and picklists, but maybe a validation rule would work here? Or is it only doable with an apex class?

Comment: I edited this for legibility. But this is exactly what validation rules are for.  In your case, it would trigger on a save where the user tries to edit a record that has Free Quantity Only.  Something like this:
**AND(ISCHANGED(Free Qnty),FreeQuantyOnly = true))**

Answer (score 0):

You can create a validation rule that'll allow to edit the `Free Qnty` only if `Free Qnty Only' is not checked, as following-

```
AND(Free_Qnty_Only__c, ISCHANGED(Free_Qnty__c))
```